# Malformed request exception when trying to send GET request

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to connect to [GDAX](https://docs.gdax.com/#api) using their REST API.

I first want to do something very simple, i.e. getting [historic rates](https://docs.gdax.com/#get-historic-rates).

I tried this:

```
private static final String GDAX_URL = "https://api.gdax.com";

    public String getCandles(final String productId, final int granularity) {
        HttpsURLConnection connection = null;

        String path = "/products/" + productId + "/candles";

        try {
            //Create connection
            URL url = new URL(GDAX_URL);
            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("granularity", String.valueOf(granularity));

            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            //Send request
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(path);
            wr.close();

            //Get Response
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();

            System.out.println(response.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

But I get a 400 code in return "Bad Request – Invalid request format".

My problem is with the passing of the path "/products//candles" and the parameters (e.g. granularity).

I don't understand what should go in the request properties and in the message itself, and in what form.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work like this:

```
URL url = new URL(GDAX_URL + path + "?granularity="+granularity);
connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Not sure how to use the DataOutputStream, so I just removed it. At least it works.